# How can i add a extra column name under the real one without deleting it in pandas?

Tags: pandas

Please see these pictures below.

[I have a dataframe like :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5ayz.png)

[I want it with an extra column name under the old one like :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9AZR.png)

I have just started learning about Pandas library :)

Comment: Please familiarise yourself with https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you, I have tried with this line of code as you give. it gives me 'distance(meter)' but i need the (meter) part under the column name  'distance'. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a `MultIndex` for the columns to add a subcolumn. For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['k', 'l', 'f'], 'distance': [100,200,300], 'speed': [6, 5, 4]})
>>> df
  name  distance  speed
0    k       100      6
1    l       200      5
2    f       300      4
>>> df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('name', ''), ('distance', '(meter)'), ('speed', '(m/s)')])
>>> df
  name distance speed
        (meter) (m/s)
0    k      100     6
1    l      200     5
2    f      300     4
```

That being said a dataframe is in the first place to manipulate data, not to present data.